# Am I missing some slicker way? Re-factoring a tibble using a tibble from NHSDataDictionaRy

Tags: r, dplyr, forcats

So I needed to re-work a data import and I saw the NHS Data Dictionary package had been released for R so I thought I could use it to map the 1's and 2's in my Gender column to more usefully named factors (i.e. Male and Female), I can never remember which is which so they definitely need sorted.

My example dataset:

| gender | age |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 |
| 2 | 43 |
| 2 | 56 |
| 1 | 72 |
| 9 | 34 |

Getting the data from NHS Data Dictionary with the new package is easy enough - if a little heavy on the typing...

It would be easy enough to do a join to my data, but that 'feels' the wrong way in this case.

```
require(dplyr)
require(forcats)
require(NHSDataDictionaRy)

myData <- tibble ( gender = as.factor(c("1","2","2","1", "9")), 
                   age = c(40,43,56,72,34)
                   )

nhs_data_lookup <- nhs_data_elements()

tableR(nhs_data_lookup$full_url[nhs_data_lookup$link_name == "PERSON STATED GENDER CODE"], 
       nhs_data_lookup$xpath_nat_code[nhs_data_lookup$link_name == "PERSON STATED GENDER CODE"] ) %>%
    select(Code, Description) -> genderLookup

set_names( genderLookup$Code, genderLookup$Description) -> genderLookup

myData %>%
    mutate(gender = fct_recode(gender, !!!genderLookup))
```

Gives:

| gender | age |
| --- | --- |
| Male | 40 |
| Female | 43 |
| Female | 56 |
| Male | 72 |
| Indeterminate (unable to be classified as either male or female) | 34 |

The above works.  But its bot ugly code!

**1. The Lookup** could be a lot cleaner.  Perhaps it just needs me to write a function?

```
NHStableR <- function(link_name) {
    nhs_data_lookup <- nhs_data_elements()
    tableR(nhs_data_lookup$full_url[nhs_data_lookup$link_name == link_name], 
           nhs_data_lookup$xpath_nat_code[nhs_data_lookup$link_name == link_name] ) %>%
        select(Code, Description) 
}

NHStableR("PERSON STATED GENDER CODE")
```

Wondering if this should be proposed as an update?

But then...

**2. The factoring** saving to an object, 'flattening' the object into a named list and then recoding the factor with it feels  very 'non-tidyverse'

So would  a named elements version of the function be better?  **OR** have I done what I seem very good at - and created 3 steps when I could have typed doSomeMagicThing(Gender) and it been sorted?

```
NHSnameR <- function(link_name) {
    nhs_data_lookup <- nhs_data_elements()
    tableR(nhs_data_lookup$full_url[nhs_data_lookup$link_name == link_name], 
           nhs_data_lookup$xpath_nat_code[nhs_data_lookup$link_name == link_name] ) %>%
        select(Code, Description) -> x
    set_names( x$Code, x$Description)
}

myData %>%
    mutate(gender = fct_recode(gender, !!!NHSnameR("PERSON STATED GENDER CODE")))
```

It could be that I don't know the data dictionary well enough to know if this would work?

So:
**1.** Have I missed something that would be tidier (pun intended!)

**2.** If not, then anyone got thoughts on this as a function?  I realize this is a bit niche!

**3.** Perhaps the easiest - if the dictionary has options not in the data (say there was no unknown gender in my data) - it generates a warning.  Can they be suppressed?

**4.** Is doing an HTTP lookup of data in the code like that bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New functions added to development release that now offer these.

```
NHStableR( "PERSON STATED GENDER CODE" )
```

```
tableRtoNamedList ( "PERSON STATED GENDER CODE", table_method = "NHStableR" )
```